# Which domain should I choose for my personal website?

Tags: postdocs, early-career, website

I have decided to create an academic personal website, but I am unsure whether I should choose a `.com` or a `.org` domain.

I have read that `.com` is mainly used by commercial organizations, whereas `.org` is intended for nonprofit use. Hence from this viewpoint I should go for `.org`, as my website will be nonprofit. On the other hand, many suggest to opt for `.com` anyway (see e.g. [here](https://www.elsevier.com/connect/creating-a-simple-and-effective-academic-personal-website)),

To complicate things further, I have verified that the domain `namesurname.org` is available, whereas `namesurname.com` is not.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2232/

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, `.com` conveys [a sense of credibility](https://business.tutsplus.com/articles/best-personal-domain-name-extension--cms-28169) so that it would be the best option, regardless of whether you pursue things commercially or not.

It seems to me that `.org` doesn't suit a private homepage.

But for a private homepage, you can generally be creative and look for any other options that suit your biography (e.g. citizenship) or name (e.g. if your surname is `Li`, why not choose `.li`?) or interest (e.g. if you do research on marine life, then you could use `.fish`).

And for research-related purposes, there are also top-level domains such as:

- `.science`
- `.engineering`
- `.academy`

Comment: Or .me, since the website is about you.

Comment: With ccTLDs like .li and .me, one should also take into consideration who controls it and how restrictions on who can own domain names under that TLD may change. (e.g. losing .eu domain names due to Brexit: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/registering-and-renewing-eu-domain-names-in-the-uk)